# Existence of a long exact sequence for sheaf cohomology

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, exact-sequence

Let $X$ be a normal variety over $\mathbb{C}$ , and let $U$ be a 
open subset of $X$, then there is an long exact sequence for singular or De Rham cohomology with compact support that relates the cohomology groups of $X$,$U$ and $X - U$.

Did exist some (maybe partial) results about sheaf cohomology in the same situation?
Im interested in the particular situation when $X$ is a normal variety with an effective action of a reducible algebraic group defined over $\mathbb{C}$.

Thanks in advance for any reference or comment!

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you want, but pages 185-186 of Iversen's "Cohomology of Sheaves" could be relevant to you.